# MySQL Load Data with single quotes around each field

Tags: mysql

I have a CSV that has single quotes around each field, the fields are separated by a tab. Trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE but it loaded it with the single quotes into each column.

Here is a sample of what the CSV data looks like:

```
'pro0718398'    '1' '$slideblk' '2018/07/01 07:07:00'   'f0\\hich\\f0\\''9188 regulations'
```

This is the code I used in MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt'INTO TABLE testTable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8) set col1=@col1, col2=@col2, col3=@col3, col4=@col4, col5=@col5, col6=@col6, col7=@col7, col8=@col8;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to it, by adding the "ENCLOSED BY '\''

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt'
INTO TABLE testTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\\' ENCLOSED BY '\''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8) 
set col1=@col1, col2=@col2, col3=@col3, col4=@col4, col5=@col5, col6=@col6, col7=@col7, col8=@col8;
```